# SVN - How to make a branch with existing unversioned folder

Tags: visual-studio, svn, repository, branch, aptana3

I have an Aptana Studio Javascript web application project under version control in using `subversion`.  I recently added some ASP.Net functionality to it and created a Visual Studio project and copied the files into that project from my Aptana Studio project.

Now, I would like to make my Visual Studio project a branch of the Aptana Studio project, but all the files are in an unversioned directory created by Visual Studio when creating the project.

How can I create a branch containing the Visual Studio project?  In the past, I've simply checked out the repository into an empty directory and then moved the existing files into that directory after it's checked out, but I worry that will mess up Visual Studio and it won't recognize the project.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. visual studio only cares about the .sln file and the structure from there down (and any project references, which are all relative links .. right?).

So, to do what you want to do, first `branch` off your trunk, then add a folder inside your branch (call it 'add_ASP_proj' or something), then create a folder with the whole visual studio copied in. `svn add` the folder and the entire visual studio solution, `svn commit`, and now you've got a branch with your ASP.NET project.

Once you're satisfied with the branch, you can merge back to trunk and get on with your day :D

Comment: My ASP.Net project contains a folder that contains the Javascript web app from the Aptana project.  Would the ASP folder that I add to the branch just contain the ASP related files or would it contain an entire copy of the JS app as it currently is within the VS project?  Obviously, I'd like to avoid have multiple copies of the JS app in the same branch.

Comment: Ah - It sounds like you're structuring it to the JS webapp is a depenendency on the ASP.NET page. I think it would be best to keep only the one copy of the JS app inside the ASP.NET project, and make the ASP.NET project the root of the project. This will result in a lot of deletes/adds, but it would be the most consistent.

Comment: Basically, the JS App is the main app and is the structure that the repo is based on.  I added the ASP part to create login functionality and simply created an ASP project with the JS App inside of it.  I'm still very new to all this so I'm not sure if that was the best way to go about it.  I'd rather not have to make a new repo for the ASP version of the project.

Comment: The other problem is that I like the Aptana environment much better for developing the html/JS parts of the app better than VS and I still have development to do within the JS App.  The ASP portion required some minor modifications to the JS App as well.  I'd like to be able to easily merge the two collections of JS files down the road.

Comment: Would it make sense to have a project within a project? In other words, could the folder within the ASP project that contains the JS App be the branch on the JS App repo and meanwhile, the ASP project could have its own repo and the JS App folder would also be part of that repo?

Answer (score 1):

So after a little more digging and thinking. I've come up with a solution...

1. I created a new repository to house the ASP.Net portion of my application and the Visual Studio project.
2. I created a new branch in my existing JS app repository for the ASP.Net related changes to the JS App.
3. I made sure both the new repository and the branch were up to date and the JS app files matched.
4. I then deleted all the JS app files from the ASP.Net project repository.
5. Finally, I used the `SVN:Externals` property within the ASP.Net project repository to link to the branch of the JS app repository.

Now, if I update the branch of the JS app within Aptana Studio, it will be updated in the ASP.Net project.  Similarly, if I update the JS app files in Visual Studio for the ASP.net project, they will be updated in the JS app Aptana Studio project.